# Testing for the docker multi stage build

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

How can i multibuild the docker image :

```bash
FROM node:16

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy source code to image
COPY . .

# Install dependencies
RUN yarn install

# Build app and start server from script
CMD ["/usr/src/app/run"]
```

Any examples ?? or links to refer...

New to docker need help with the issue ??

Comment: What do you mean by "multibuild"?  This looks like a pretty routine single-stage Dockerfile and I'd expect you to be able to `docker build` it normally; what problems are you running into?

Comment: The dockefile is good and runs without any issue. Need the help on how i can create a multi-stage build with the above code some examples would really help or links as well.